# Another 'what am I' riddle (easy)!

Tags: riddle, word

> I am colorless, odorless, tasteless, and invisible
> When I am inside of you, you sound funny
> But too much of me would kill you
> And when I touch fire, it gets angry
>
> What am I ?

Comment: This seems really broad. From the number of answers already, there are a ton of colorless, odorless/tasteless gasses that change the pitch of your voice, are dangerous in large quantities, and react with fire... Perhaps you could add some other clues (Maybe something about its chemical formula) to narrow down the possible answers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm going to say

> Helium (gas)

I am colorless, odorless, tasteless, invisible

> Yeah, those seem to match up, although Helium from a store tank usually has a bit of a scent to it.

When I am inside of you, you sound funny

> Your voice gets higher when you inhale Helium

But too much of me would kill you

> Over-inhalation of Helium frequently knocks people out, and too much Helium without fresh air would indeed kill you

And when I touch fire, it gets angry

> This is a bit more of a stretch, but since Helium isn't flammable, perhaps fire gets angry because it can't burn it up, and burning things is pretty much all fire wants to do.

Answer (score 2):

It's

> Hydrogen gas $\text{H}_2$

I am colorless, odorless, tasteless, invisible

> Just like most gases

When I am inside of you, you sound funny

> Also like Helium

But too much of me would kill you

> Well, if there's no oxygen anymore, you die.

And when I touch fire, it gets angry

> $\text{H}_2$ burns like hell.

Answer (score 1):

It is

> Nitrogen (N)

As,

> Nitrogen is colorless, odorless, tasteless, and invisible

When I am inside of you, you sound funny

> Nitrous oxide (laughing gas, as it is usually called), when inhaled makes us laugh  OR it can be cracking of knuckles / body joints which is due to Nitrogen / its compound in gaseous form.
>  It is poisonous in large quantities, when inhaled

And when I touch fire, it gets angry

> It does not support a fire rather it tries to explode / form an explosive environment.

Answer (score 1):

> Oxygen

I am colorless, odorless, tasteless, and invisible

> Well, it is, unless someone "cut the cheese" (but that's not oxygen anyway)

When I am inside of you, you sound funny

> The arteries transport oxygen.

But too much of me would kill you

> [Oxygen poisoning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxygen_toxicity)

And when I touch fire, it gets angry

> Oxygen makes the fire burn.

Comment: How does it *make you sound funny*?

Answer (score 1):

you are

> Methane

I am colorless, odorless, tasteless, and invisible

> methane in its natural state is odorless colorless and tasteless

When I am inside of you, you sound funny

> tummy rumble!

But too much of me would kill you

> methane can be deadly!

And when I touch fire, it gets angry

> methane is a natural gas used for burning!

Answer (score 1):

Its

> Nitrous oxide (N2O)

I am colorless, odorless, tasteless, and invisible

> At room temperature it is colourless, invisible ,odourless and tasteless(with a very slight sweet taste that is negligible)

When I am inside of you, you sound funny

> Its also name as "laughing gas" due to the euphoric effects upon inhaling it.

But too much of me would kill you

> Nitrous oxide is used as anaesthetic but overdose blocks blood vessels and can kill a person.

And when I touch fire, it gets angry

> Though it is non-flammable at room temperature but when mixed with a flammable material it gets very dangerous by providing more oxygen than air alone, hence a more powerful combustion.

Answer (score 1):

It really could be almost anything, so I'll guess

> Sulphur Hexaflouride

I am colorless, odorless, tasteless, and invisible

> It is all of these

When I am inside of you, you sound funny

> It's heavier than oxygen so it makes your voice sound super deep

But too much of me would kill you

> Like helium it can make you suffocate if you inhale too much.

And when I touch fire, it gets angry

> Creates toxic fumes when introduced with fire

Comment: Sulphur compounds having no odour is rare